# Changing variables from console

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

How do you change these variables from console?

I want to know how to change variables from a console to change objects in the game. But when I tried to do so, the console outputs "(variable) undefined".

This is the game: https://yassernoori.herokuapp.com/

And these are the variables that I want to modify:
https://github.com/yassernoori/pong/blob/master/pongOnline/SETTINGS.js

(I mainly want to modify the SETTINGS.js, but also the other files in PongOnline, too)

So basically, I want to know how to do this to make mods for my game.

Sorry for the bad question, i'm only 13.

Comment: Just in case we are on the same page - are you trying to temporarily change the variables from console and test them?

Comment: Yes, temporarily. I want it to change not only on the clients computer, but also on others people, too.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems of the thing you are trying to achieve. 
First of all: 
You are trying to reach a variable that is rendered server side (with node). This way you won't be able to reach this cause its saved in a module.

Second:
His code is wrapped around an IIFE. This makes it impossible to reach the code wrapped inside of it. This prevents action like reaching variables that can't be modified.

So conclusion. You can't reach them in this application

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to reach variables from the console, those variables have to be on the global scope (like `window`).

You can only change variables that are on the current scope, so, if you try to set a breakpoint on `settings.js` you could change values there only when you're at the breakpoint.

Comment: How could I do that, can you give me a sample code? I could also modify the settings.js file.